# How to use explicit waits when page factories are used in webdriver code

Tags: selenium-webdriver, wait, factory, explicit

I use page factories in my webdriver code, If i want to use `"ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated"` which take a By object, how is it possible to use the WebElements declared using Page Factories. Should i simply use the locator exg(`By.id("xyz")`)... But that amounts to duplicating the locators. I understand this issue has been raised in many forums. I want to know whether there is an elegant solution for this problem.

Comment: Not at the moment.  Right now you would have to store your By as well as the WebElement in your page factory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(WebElement)` should do the trick.